# Shift+tab no longer works on terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, iterm

I have a 2017 MacBook Pro Retina 13", running the latest version of macOS. I use Iterm + zhsrc as terminal configuration but a few weeks ago my shortcut Alt + Tab stopped working.

If I'm executing the command `ls` and I have multiple choices they are displayed underneath the command. With `Tab` I can scroll those options down, and I used to use `Shift + Tab` to scroll in the opposite direction but now it doesn't work, and I can scroll the only in one direction.

Do you know what could have happened?

EDIT: Updated shortcut

Comment: idk the apps, but have you tried shift/tab ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant Shift + Tab, not Alt + tab, I'm gonna update the question!